# How is commonly named a weakest possible H0

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

**Is there a commonly used name for the property of a null hypothesis for being "weakest possible" ?**

There is in general several possibilities to write $H0$ for a specific test. All possible $H0$ ensure that $H0 \implies \forall \alpha, P(p_{value}\leq\alpha)\leq \alpha$. Some of them ensure that $H0 \iff \forall \alpha, P(p_{value}\leq\alpha)\leq \alpha$ and those $H0$ are then weakest possible but I do not find this name on litterature.

I guess this is more or less equivalent to the property (under possible assumption) :

$H1=\bar{H0} \implies \forall \alpha\in]0,1], \forall \beta\in]0,1], \exists K\in \mathbb{N},  n>K=>P(p_{value}<\alpha)>1-\beta$ 
(In other words when n tends towards $+\infty$, not rejecting $H0$ is equivalent to accept it.)

For most current test $H0$ there is an easily writtable $H0$ which is weakest possible. Let's take as example the Mann Whitney rank-sum test for which there is two commonly used defintion of hyopthesis (without counting the erroneous ones) :

1. Preiliminary hyopthesis : "*the two distributions of X and Y are the same, except of a possible shift*" ; $H0$ is then : "*The shift is $0$*". 
   This $H0$ is well "weakest possible".
2. There is no preliminary assumption and $H0$ is "*X and Y follow the same distribution*". This assumption is not weakest possible. As example with N=2, $P(X=0)=1, P(Y=1)=.5, P(Y=-1)=-.5$ , X and Y do not follow the same distribution but $\forall \alpha, P(p_{value}\leq\alpha)\leq\alpha$. Another example which do not respect the second property : X and Y follow two gaussian distributions with the same average and different variance. They are not following the same distribution but $P(p_{value}<\alpha)$ do not tends towards 1. (Note however on this case  $\exists \alpha,P(p_{value}<\alpha)>\alpha$ )

I guess this may be a commonly discussed topic but I do not have the right keywords to find references.

Comment: Thanks, The first question is the most important so I remove the second one

Comment: Thanks for acting on my earlier Comment, which I've deleted.  Let's clear up the meaning of "weakest possible" used in both the title and the opening paragraph as a property of the null hypothesis.  The phrase lacks two important referrants.  To what kind of things is the null hypothesis being compared, and what measure of weakness (or strength) applies.  Some of this may be implicit in the second paragraph, beginning "if H0 is wrong...", but I cannot identify how the comparison is being proposed.

Comment: Really thanks for your comment, it helps also to clear up my mind. I have tried accordingly to clear up the problem, I hope it answers your question.